# How to check array empty or not in php

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework

I am having huge array. Its structure is like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 57060
            [customer] => 1         
            [desc] => Customer Object
                (
                    [id] => 51716
                    [name] => abc xyz           
                    [supplier] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [@size] => 1
                            [Supplier] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [@chainCode] => EP
                                    [@id] => 13
                                )
                        )

                    [Types] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [@size] => 9
                            [Type] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [@Code] => 394431
                                            [@TypeId] => 497374                                
                                                (
                                                    [@size] => 27
                                                    [Amenity] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [@amenityId] => 8149624
                                                                    [amenity] => Air Conditioning
                                                                )

                                                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [@amenityId] => 8149701
                                                                    [amenity] => 
                                                                )
                                                          )
                                                          .....
                                                          ..... and so on
```

I trying to check simply if the above array is empty or not.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><b>View my Reviews</b></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan=10>
            <div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php
    if (!empty($this->revArr)) {
        foreach ($this->revArr as $review):
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1">
                    <?php echo ($review['name'] == '') ? 'a guest' : $review['name']; ?> <br/>on <span style="font-size:11px;"><?php echo date("M j, Y", strtotime($review['created_at'])); ?></span>

                </td>
                <td class="col2">                   
                    <span class="name"><a href="/hotelreview/<?php echo $review['hotelId']; ?>"><?php echo $review['Info']->Name; ?></a></span>
                    <br/>
                    <span class="address"><?php
                echo $review['Info']->address1;
                if ($review['Info']->address2 != '') {
                    echo ' ' . $review['Info']->address2;
                }
                if ($review['Info']->address3 != '') {
                    echo ' ' . $review['hotelInfo']->address3;
                }
                ?></span>

                    <div style="margin-top:10px;">
                        <h4><b><?php echo ($review['title'] == '') ? 'A Review By' : $review['title']; ?></b></h4>
                        <p><?php
                $detail = str_replace("\r", "\n", $review['detail']);
                $detail = preg_replace("#\n+#", "\n", $detail);
                echo str_replace("\n", "</p><p>", $detail);
                        ?></p>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

        <?php endforeach; ?>  
        <tr>
            <td colspan=10 style="text-align:right;">
                <?php echo $pagination; ?>                
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } {
        ?>
        <tr style="text-align: center;">
            <td>No Review Found !!</td>
        </tr>
    <?php }
    ?>
</table>
```

Where I am going wrong? Why above all conditions are not working?

Need Help.

Thanks.

Comment: Simply you can check if an array is empty or not using `if(empty($arrayName))`.

Comment: is the above the output of `print_r($this->revArr);` ??

Comment: There was a similar question yesterday. The problem was actually the part of the code posted was in a function and the variable wasn't being passed or global. Because the person didn't post enough code it took them an hour to work out instead of finding an answer in minutes. Please post more relevant code.

Comment: @popnoodles : ok I'll modify my post. Please wait

Comment: Sorry that extra code doesn't help. Where is `$this->revArr` coming from?

Comment: @popnoodles : Its coming from the API

Comment: The API? What API? Where is the code that sets it? Where is that code you're showing running? `$this` requires context. You're not showing that.

Comment: @popnoodles: I am getting an API from xml request which giving the array which I posted in code. I want to simply check if the above array is empty or not containing any data then simply display not data found otherwise list out the functionality. I thing this information is enough anybody to understand where's the problem.

Comment: If you believe so. Good luck with that.

Comment: @popnoodles : Ok Thanks...but please don't downvote bcoz I don't thing so there is any wrong with my question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22621/discussion-between-ultimate-and-popnoodles)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068220/check-if-array-is-null-or-not-in-php?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that you just forgot the `else`? From what I see this code will always output

> "No Data Found"

even if data is present. If data is present it should also output the data as requested.

```
//snippet
<?php endforeach; ?>  
        <tr>
            <td colspan=10 style="text-align:right;">
                <?php echo $pagination; ?>                
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } else {//there should be an else here
        ?>
        <tr style="text-align: center;">
            <td>No Review Found !!</td>
        </tr>
    <?php }
    ?>
</table>
```

Are you sure your api returns **nothing** if it fails to find the data? Most times an api will return `False` or an `error array` on failure so testing for `empty` may not be appropriate.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
if(is_array($this->revArr) && count($this->revArr)){
  //code for displaying array information
}else{
   echo "No data found";
}
```

The `count` function will return true if the variable is a string, so you need to check that it is an array first.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is it letting through empty arrays, or is it not letting through populated arrays?

Comment: its still going in `else` condition.

Comment: The either `$this->revArr` is not an array, or it contains no data. There is no other option. What happens when you do a `var_dump` just before the `if` statement?

Comment: `var_dump` prints the array

Comment: And what happens when you add this just before the `if` statement: `echo gettype($this->revArr);`

Answer (score 0):

Take a Look:
[empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

[isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

[is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)

Comment: `<?php
function array_empty($mixed) {
    if (is_array($mixed)) {
        foreach ($mixed as $value) {
            if (!array_empty($value)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    elseif (!empty($mixed)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
?>`

Answer (score 0):

okay try these 2 steps

```
reset($array_name)
key = key($array_name)
```

it will return NULL if there is no key otherwise returns the first key

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to check if an array is empty. There is no other easy way.

```
// Checks if an array is empty by values recursively.
// If check_all_elements is true, all the elements will be required to be not empty.
function is_array_empty($array, $check_all_elements = false)
{
    if (!is_array($array) || empty($array))
        return true;

    $elements = count($array);
    foreach ($array as $element)
    {
        if (empty($element) || (is_array($element) && is_array_empty($element, $check_all_elements)))
        {
            if ($check_all_elements)
                return true;
            else $elements--;
        }
    }
    return empty($elements);
}
```