# Checking if an array within an array is empty/null in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm checking an array if it contains a few things and an array inside it is empty. How do I achieve this?

I've tried checking it on `empty`, `inArray` and a regular condition in the if.

Screenshot of the array (`assignedTo`, which needs to be null/empty in order for the if to be true):

[image]

```
for($i = 1; $i < $this->pages['maxPages']+1; $i++) {            
        $response = $this->client->get('v1/tickets/search.json', [
            'query' => ['page' => $i, 'assignedTo[]' => null, 'statuses[]' => 'active', 'waiting', 'sortDir' => 'desc', 'sortBy' => 'updatedAt']
        ]);

        //Verwekt de data gekregen van de API
        $json = (string)$response->getBody()->getContents();
        $decoded = json_decode($json, true);

        //Haalt de lengte van de result array op
        $arrayLength = sizeof($decoded['tickets']);

        //Slaat de resultaten op in de bijbehorende variabele. De if statement loopt nog na of de tickets écht aan de filters voldoen. Het komt nog wel eens voor dat er tickets worden opgehaald die niet opgehaald moeten worden volgens de filters.
        for($int = 0; $int < $arrayLength; $int++) {
            if($decoded['tickets'][$int]['status'] === 'active' || $decoded['tickets'][$int]['status'] === 'waiting on customer' && empty($decoded['tickets'][$int]['assignedTo'])) {                    
                $newticketamount++;
                $activetickets[] = $decoded['tickets'][$int];
            }
        }
    }
```

So, I want the if to be executed when the `$decoded['tickets'][$int]['assignedTo']` is empty. Currently it has both the tickets that ARE assigned and the ones that aren't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check If array is null or not in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068220/check-if-array-is-null-or-not-in-php)

Comment: @devgianlu As I've stated. empty() isn't working.

Comment: If you look further down, some user suggested to use `isset`. But anyway I think the solution has already been provided down here.

Comment: Adding some () around the OR statement did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap `||` condition in one and then add `&&` with it:-

```
if( empty( $decoded['tickets'][$int]['assignedTo'] ) && ($decoded['tickets'][$int]['status'] === 'active' || $decoded['tickets'][$int]['status'] === 'waiting on customer')){

    $newticketamount++;
    $activetickets[] = $decoded['tickets'][$int];
}
```

Even a much better approach [for readability as well as better implementation]

```
if( empty( $decoded['tickets'][$int]['assignedTo'] ) ){

    if( ($decoded['tickets'][$int]['status'] === 'active' || $decoded['tickets'][$int]['status'] === 'waiting on customer')){

        $newticketamount++;
        $activetickets[] = $decoded['tickets'][$int];
    }
}
```

Note:- because of [Operator Precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) you faced problem.

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly! Thanks a ton. Can you tell me why it has to be put between ( )?

Comment: @ScottvanDuin  added note for that.

Comment: Was going to but I forgot, sorry!

Comment: @ScottvanDuin  no issue, glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

Empty works perfectly fine, I think the problem is with logical operators and its order

You need to put parenthesis there

```
if (($decoded['tickets'][$int]['status'] === 'active' || $decoded['tickets'][$int]['status'] === 'waiting on customer') && empty($decoded['tickets'][$int]['assignedTo'])) {
```

This will check if status is `active` or `waiting on customer` AND `assignedTo` is not empty

Answer (score 0):

Should work like this

`if(in_array($decoded['tickets'][$int]['status'],['active','waiting on customer']) && empty($decoded['tickets'][$int]['assignedTo']))`